# Single sign-on for all Office 365 users

Tags: single-sign-on, office365

I've been attempting to create a single sign-on for Office 365 users unsuccessfully. How can I achive this not for one company (or single Azure AD) but for every user that already has an office 365 account? I need this because I will be creating a service for Office 365 and I need to authenticate users to provide configuration options that could be personalized over the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably a better question to go on superuser.com

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about your scenario? Do you want to create an application that any Office 365 user can sign in to using their O365 accounts? What environment are you developing in?